# Google Maps Autocomplete fail with WKWebView on Cordova iOS

Tags: google-maps, cordova, autocomplete, wkwebview

I am developing a Cordova app and I recently installed WKWebView(https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview) on the iOS version.
I'm using the Google Maps Place Autocomplete API but it stopped working with WKWebView giving me this error if I type on the input field:

```
This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console:
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/places_backend?project=_ 
For more information on authentication and Google Maps Javascript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
```

If I go back to normal webview (UIWebView) it works, so I don't think it's a code problem, and the API Project is fully authorized to use the APIs.
I think it has something to do with the CORS change in WKWebView but I really don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Did you enable any restrictions to the API key in the google console?

Comment: No, it has no restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.
I don't know how this is possible but I just created a new API Key and this new key works.. :/